# Crop a pattern-based area of multiple images in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a big number of screenshots that need to be cropped. All the images look similar - there is a rectangular window with blue border, containing some graphical elements inside. This window is contained inside another one but I need to crop only the inner window. Across all images the dimensions of the inner window are different and so is the content. The content in most cases includes elements with rectangular form and sometimes - blue border, the same border as the inner window. I am mentioning this because I am thinking of the following flow:

A script that goes through all images in the target directory. For each of them:

- Find the area to be cropped (inner window)
- Crop the area
- Save the file

How can this be done? Python is not compulsory, can be any other too also.

Comment: I think it is. Can you put here some examples of those images with the rectangles?

Comment: Nope, it's confident :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not straightforward but this is a possible recipe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def synthimage():
    w,h = 300,200
    im = np.random.randint(0,255,(w,h,3))/255
    xa = np.random.randint(50,w-60)
    xb = xa + np.random.randint(50,90)
    ya = np.random.randint(50,h-60)
    yb = ya + np.random.randint(20,50)
    im[xa:xb,ya] = np.array([1,0,0])
    im[xa:xb,yb] = np.array([1,0,0])
    im[xa,ya:yb] = np.array([1,0,0])
    im[xb,ya:yb] = np.array([1,0,0])
    return im

def getRectPoints(im):
    x,y = [],[]
    for i in range(im.shape[0]):
        for j in range(im.shape[1]):
            if (im[i,j]-np.array([1,0,0])).sum()==0:
                x.append(i)
                y.append(j)
    return np.array(x),np.array(y)

def denoise(x,y):
    nx,ny = [],[]
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        d = np.sqrt((x[i]-x)**2+(y[i]-y)**2)
        m = d<2
        if len(m.nonzero()[0])>2:
            nx.append(x[i])
            ny.append(y[i])
    return np.array(nx),np.array(ny)

im = synthimage()    
plt.imshow(np.swapaxes(im,0,1),origin='lower',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

x,y = getRectPoints(im)
plt.scatter(x,y,c='red')
plt.xlim(0,300)
plt.ylim(0,200)
plt.show()

nx,ny = denoise(x,y)
plt.scatter(nx,ny,c='red')
plt.xlim(0,300)
plt.ylim(0,200)
plt.show()

#Assuming rectangle has no rotation (otherwise check Scipy ConveHull)
xmi = nx.min()
xma = nx.max()
ymi = ny.min()
yma = ny.max()

new = np.ones(im.shape)
new[xmi:xma,ymi:yma] = im[xmi:xma,ymi:yma]
plt.imshow(np.swapaxes(new,0,1),origin='lower',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

, the name of the functions should be self-explaining. Synthetic data was generated for the purpose of this exercise. The results are (in order):

[image: Picture with red rectangle]

[image: Extracting bright Red pixels]

[image: Denoising the extraction]

[image: Extracting the regular bounding box of the image]

Obviously each one of this steps can be changed depending on the requirements but this would be a functional solution for the majority of case-studies.